# Chrome extension History API not working properly?

Tags: javascript, google-chrome, google-chrome-extension, browser-history

I am creating my first Chrome extension, the extension will allow user to enter a search term and that search term will searched through the browser history and the results will be shown, after which the user can delete the results by clicking on a delete button. Here is my code -

```
window.onload = function() {
function getHistory() {
  var div = document.getElementById('all');
  var search = document.getElementById("search").value;
  if (search === '') {
    div.innerHTML = '';
    div.innerHTML = div.innerHTML + 'Nothing To Search.';
  }
  else {
    var microseconds = 1000 * 60 * 60 * 24 * 365 * 45;
    var start = (new Date).getTime() - microseconds;
  chrome.history.search({text: search, startTime: start, maxResults: 200}, function(data) {
    if(Object.keys(data).length === 0) {
    div.innerHTML = '';
      div.innerHTML = div.innerHTML + 'Nothing Found.';
    }
    else {
      div.innerHTML = '';
        data.forEach(function(page) {
        div.innerHTML = div.innerHTML + '<p>'+page.title+'</p> <a href='+page.url+' target="_blank"><p>'+page.url+'</p></a> <br>';
    });
    document.getElementById('delete').onclick = deleteHistory;
  }
});
  }
}

function deleteHistory() {
  var search = document.getElementById("search").value;
  var microseconds = 1000 * 60 * 60 * 24 * 365 * 45;
  var start = (new Date).getTime() - microseconds;
  chrome.history.search({text: search, startTime: start, maxResults: 200}, function(data) {
    var div = document.getElementById('all');
    data.forEach(function(page) {
        chrome.history.deleteUrl({url: page.url}, function() {
          div.innerHTML = '';
          div.innerHTML = div.innerHTML + 'All Clear!';
        });
    });
});
}

document.getElementById('get').onclick = getHistory;
}
```

So far everything is working, except when i delete history, it is deleted but it still shows in browser history. 
Please tell me what am i doing wrong? Also is there anything else that i could have improved in the code?
Thank you.

Comment: what is console.log(JSON.stringify(page))?

Comment: Sorry, i dont see console.log(JSON.stringify(page)).  What do you mean?

Comment: Add console.log(JSON.stringify(page)) inside your .foreach().

Comment: I checked with this, my delete function is working fine. If i delete history through the extension it does not show again in console but still shows in the browser history.

Comment: maybe sync is repopulating deleted items?

Comment: How do i check that?

Comment: disable sync and see if it happens

Comment: you are right, that is the problem, how do i work around this? the user of the extension might have sync enabled, this will cause the same problem there too.

Comment: I have no idea. I think there is reported bug on crbug...but I can't find it right now.

Comment: maybe to notify users if history sync is enabled, that there is bug. BUT pls check if I'm right in the first place about bug, or there is a solution for it

Comment: you are right, this is a reported bug, and it is still not fixed. here is the link https://code.google.com/p/chromium/issues/detail?id=395955

Answer (score 2, accepted):

So this is a bug with chromium and it is already reported here - https://code.google.com/p/chromium/issues/detail?id=395955 . The bug is still not fixed, so unfortunately nothing can be done about this issue right now.